# Angular CLI how to merge json files

Tags: json, angular-cli

Is it possible to natively in configuration file of angular cli merge json files.
For example i have a lot of json files in different directories like locale-en-GB.json and i want to merge them into one locale-en-GB.file. So angular 2 translator can use it.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: I didn't found how to do it natively. So i'm doing this using grunt, gulp and if you eject the webpack file you can do it also via webpack. The reason why i dont want to eject it makes migrating to another version of cli harder.